# Java JNA sendMessage() not found

Tags: java, jna, sendmessage, user32

I'm trying to use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) [(Overview)](https://github.com/twall/jna#readme) to send messages to an application when minimized or not on top (mouse click for example), and the I found that people are using 
com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32.[SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)A( hW, 0x0201, 0, 0);

But i can't found this function in this class.

Can someone give me an example of how to implement it if I'm doing it wrong?

CODE:

```
User32 user32;
Pointer hW = user32.GetForegroundWindow().getPointer();
user32.SendMessageA( hW, 0x0201, 0, 0 );
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: In fact there is only these lines, I'm trying to use to send message to hW ()

Comment: user32 is null here...

Comment: You have to add the JNA JAR into your classpath.

Comment: Aubin thanks for suggestions, I think that Chuck Fricano answer is what i was looking for., i just need some more help

Answer (score 5):

```
public interface User32Ext extends User32 {
User32Ext USER32EXT = (User32Ext) Native.loadLibrary("user32",

        User32Ext.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

HWND FindWindowEx(HWND lpParent, HWND lpChild, String lpClassName,
        String lpWindowName);

HWND GetTopWindow(HWND hwnd);

HWND GetParent(HWND hwnd);

HWND GetDesktopWindow();

int SendMessage(HWND hWnd, int dwFlags, byte bVk, int dwExtraInfo);

int SendMessage(HWND hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, String lParam);

void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

void SwitchToThisWindow(HWND hWnd, boolean fAltTab);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define this function yourself.   All windows functions are not predefined.

Example: (untested - usage example only)

```
public interface MyUser32 extends User32 {
    MyUser32 INSTANCE = (MyUser32)Native.loadLibrary("user32", MyUser32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    LRESULT SendMessage(HWND hWnd, int Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
}
```

Comment: what's wParam and lParam plz?, and do you knwo when I can get a list of all Msg

Comment: Look it up in the win API doc.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx