# Send a user-defined Windows-message through JNA

Tags: java, c++, winapi, jna

I want a simple but hard thing: to send a specific user-defined Windows-message from the JNA side in order this message to be catched by a message-loop (`GetMessage()`/`DispatchMessage()`) on the C++ side and that message loop will be then interrupted. Actually it should be performed by the button click in Swing GUI. My questions and considerations:

1) Suppose for example I defined on the C++ side my own message as `#define WM_CUSTOM_MSG (WM_USER+42)` and of course add an appropriate if-statement for interruption inside my message-loop on C++ side. But my purpose is to send this message from java.

2) To do this I wrote the following:

```
public class User32Ext {
    interface User32Interface extends User32 {
        User32Interface INSTANCE = Native.load("user32",

                User32Interface.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

        @Override
        HWND FindWindowEx(HWND lpParent, HWND lpChild, String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

        HWND GetTopWindow(HWND hwnd);

        HWND GetParent(HWND hwnd);

        @Override
        HWND GetDesktopWindow();

        int SendMessage(HWND hWnd, int Msg, IntByReference wParam, IntByReference lParam);

        void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

        void SwitchToThisWindow(HWND hWnd, boolean fAltTab);

    }

    private final User32Interface u32 = User32Interface.INSTANCE;

    public User32Ext() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void sendInterruptMessage(final String windowName) {
        try {
            final User32.HWND hwnd = u32.FindWindowEx(null, null, null, windowName);
            final int msg = 0x400 + 42;
            final User32.WPARAM wparam = new User32.WPARAM();
            final User32.LPARAM lparam = new User32.LPARAM();
            final LRESULT res = u32.SendMessage(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
        } catch (final RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

and then just create an object of this dummy class and call `sendInterruptMessage` with my `JFrame`'s title as parameter in the button event.

Sadly, on the both sides absolutely no effect was detected. I'm pretty much sure I did some fatal error, because I'm not expirienced enough with Windows and JNA programming. So, could you tell me, at least am I right conceptually, implementing the desired result like this? Or there are just some programming errors on the Java side. Thanks!

P.S. if it could be implemented without sending a custom message, but with some standard Windows message, that's perfectly fine, I just want to be sure, the only thing this message does is to interrupt my C++ message loop.

Comment: Why are there two mappings for `SendMessage`?  Second one looks closer to the one I see at [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage), but wParam and lParam should be `IntByReference` not `int` nor `String`.  Unless there's some other mapping somewhere that I'm not seeing?  (Or, I see you've instantiated the actual wrapper classes at the bottom of your code, but how does this possibly compile?  Unless you're calling the parent User32 version of SendMessage, but you're just sending default values for those params....)

Comment: Yes, actually it should be commented, I forgot to add comment, I edited op post, and deleted the first version, yes, the second one was valid. And I'm sorry, I don't get your message in brackets. If you mean that I mixed up definition and implementation - yes, you are right, but I think it doesn't matter since I need this class only for one functional call and I wrote the code fastly to check the concept.

Comment: I changed the types of `lparam` and `wparam` in the definition to `IntByReference` and nothing is changed.

Comment: Messages in the `WM_USER + x` range aren't custom messages. Those are per-window messages. Custom messages should go in the `WM_APP + x` range. The system will not marshal pointed-to data across process boundaries in either case, in case you want to send things like string data across.

Comment: To clarify, you are defining `wparam` and `lparam` as `WPARAM` and `LPARAM` types in your `sendInterruptMessage()` method. This fulfills the "pointer to integer" function so my initial suggestion `IntByReference` should be these types instead.  But this means that `u32.SendMessage()` call at the bottom of your code snippet is *not* calling the `SendMessage()` mapping in the top portion. It's calling something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When mapping WINAPI functions with JNA, you must take care to exactly match the Windows API definitions with appropriate Java/JNA types.  Some of your mappings are wrong.  The last two arguments to `SendMessage` are a `WPARAM` and `LPARAM`, which you appear to be using in your `sendInterruptMessage()` mapping.  These are calling the [already-mapped `SendMessage` function in the JNA project](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/cc1acdac02e4d0dda93ba01bbe3a3435b8933dab/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/User32.java#L2487).  It doesn't matter what you're putting in your own `SendMessage` mapping since you're not even calling it, as you're using different types.  Delete that.  Also delete the two methods you have put `@Override` on from the superclass.  You have no reason to overwrite what they are already doing.

Actually, on further inspection, it appears as if you've copied the code someone else wrote in 2014 [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21300128/1161484).  However, the mappings you need [were added to the JNA project](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/commit/32ea99a681560f160d0dbdda757f7f447b81d794) in 2017.  Copying code without knowing what it does is not a recipe for success.  Your entire interface is not needed.  Just call JNA's `User32` interface.

In your call to `FindWindowEx` you're passing null for the first three arguments and only placing a String in the fourth argument. This seems to mismatch [the API which does not appear to allow null as the third argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexa).  Have you checked whether the returned handle is null?  It probably is, and per the API you can use `GetLastError` to look at that error code, which is likely associated with incorrect arguments.

The docs for that third argument specify,

> If lpszClass is a string, it specifies the window class name. The
>   class name can be any name registered with RegisterClass or
>   RegisterClassEx, or any of the predefined control-class names, or it
>   can be MAKEINTATOM(0x8000). In this latter case, 0x8000 is the atom
>   for a menu class. For more information, see the Remarks section of
>   this topic.

It does not appear as if you are doing this as required.

If that first call is succeeding (which would surprise me), it would be instructive for you to evaluate the `LRESULT` return from the existing `SendMessage` call and see if it indicates success or generates an error code.  In fact, you are probably passing it a null handle, in which case it's no surprise that nothing is happening.

Starting out by checking method return values that indicate success/failure and evaluating the error codes should help you debug.

Finally, as ponited out by [iinspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) in the comments, the code you're passing isn't a custom message.  [According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#application-defined-messages),

> Message-identifier values are used as follows:
>
> - The system reserves message-identifier values in the range 0x0000    through 0x03FF (the value of WM_USER  – 1) for system-defined
>     messages. Applications cannot use these values for private messages.
> - Values in the range 0x0400 (the value of WM_USER) through 0x7FFF are    available for message identifiers for private window classes.
> - If your application is marked version 4.0, you can use    message-identifier values in the range 0x8000 (WM_APP) through 0xBFFF 
>     for private messages.
> - The system returns a message identifier in the range 0xC000 through    0xFFFF when an application calls the RegisterWindowMessage function
>     to register a message. The message identifier returned by this
>     function is guaranteed to be unique throughout the system. Use of
>     this function prevents conflicts that can arise if other applications 
>     use the same message identifier for different purposes.

Reading the WINAPI documentation to know what's expected in each parameter will help you find the right values to pass and is critical to getting expected results from your code.

Comment: `ULONG_PTR` is NOT a "pointer to a native Long", that would be `(L)PLONG` instead.  `ULONG_PTR` is a pointer-sized unsigned integer, ie a 4-byte unsigned integer in a 32bit process, and an 8-byte unsigned integer in a 64bit process.  Big difference.  See [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I knew that once, and forgot... :(

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, your critic is harsh but deserved. Sorry, I'm very bad at those system programming fields. Actually you are right, I don't need this dummy copied interface. I have only one question: if `WM_USER +42` for the custom messages was incorrect and I should use `WM_APP+42` then how should I set up wparam and lparam arguments for the `SendMessage` function with such a message? I'm a bit lost, because I read a comment to this function in jna docs and it is said that for `WM_USER` they should be numeric values, but for `WM_COPYDATA` not. And what for `WM_APP +`?

Comment: And also I used three null values as arguments to the function `FindWindowEx` because I use in my C++ code a following call of a simple FindWindow: `FindWindow (0, L"mywindowname")` and it works perfectly okay, but now I see that I should probably use empty string instead of null for the third argument. Or maybe use not ex version but usual one as now I see from this jna documentation, that everything is already mapped.

Comment: The question is also, whether `SendMessage` is the best option for sending (and catching on the other side which is more important) Windows messages? But I've read don't remeber where, that `PostMessage` alternative won't deliver a custom message so easy.

Comment: You may be fine with your existing zero values for the `wparam` and `lparam` arguments, particularly with a custom message. I think they're intended to provide additional information to specific standardized messages.  For example (picked one randomly) the [CCM_DPISCALE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/ccm-dpiscale) message specifies "true" for the WPARAM argument.   These are available for you to send extra info beyond just the message code, if you need to.

Comment: As for what's best, that really depends on what's available on the C++ side and how much control you have over it.  Options could include simply writing text to a file that's read in by the other side, or a shared memory location, or an open port listening for messages.  This link for Windows [Interprocess Communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) should give you a good summary of your options.

Comment: Also (less random this time!) the [WM_COPYDATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-copydata) message specifies what to put in those parameters... a handle in one, a (pointer to a) structure in the other, where the structure further contains a pointer to the data.  I don't know how complex your data is, it sounds just like a single signal, in which case you don't need all this detail.